# undefined reference,gmp lib

Tags: c, cygwin, undefined-reference

I installed the gmp libraries in cygwin via its installer. I tried to compile a simple program with gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>


int
main(void)
{
    mpz_t test;
    int i;

    printf("enter number\n");
    gmp_scanf("%Z",&test);
    gmp_printf("test=%Z",test);
    i=mpz_probab_prime_p(test,5);
    if(i)
        printf("prime\n");
    else
        printf("not prime\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But I got this:

```
 /cygdrive/c/Users/xxxxx/Documents/NetBeansProjects/rsa_system/main.c:13: undefined reference to  `__imp____gmp_scanf'
```

This is the first time that I try to use a non-standard library and I'm getting confused here. My compiler is set to Cygwin and I've done all the installation part. Any ideas on what may be wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking gcc to link GMP?

i.e.: `gcc -lgmp main.c ....`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to think about is the order in which you link in GMP libraries. If you link in GMP first, and then GMPXX (i.e. the C++ extension), then you'll be in trouble. Link in GMP first and then GMPXX.